# Firefox not loading polymer vulcanized files

Tags: html, firefox, polymer, web-component, vulcanize

I know firefox doesnt support HTML link import , but it was supossed to work If I included the webcomponents library.
Either way , its not working , firefox doesnt throw any errors but It refuses to load any file inside the vulcanized html file

```
    <script src="/static/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/static/vulcanize/base.html">
```

There is not way to import an HTML file on firefox ? 
Can I solve this error using a different approach ?

Comment: check your network tab to see if `webcomponents` are getting loaded. Vulcanization has worked for me in Firefox.

Comment: It should work What's in the console's Network tab?